# How to concatenate the dictionary to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to concatenate multiple dictionaries to dataframe . I have tried it in multiple ways but i'm getting errors.

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Type Of Orders', 'Backlogs'])
print(d)
columnlist_D=['Base order D', 'Base order mont', 'Move order D', 'Move order mon']
for column in columnlist_D:
        data = {'Type Of Orders': column, 'Backlogs': 18226}
                # d = d.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        #d = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
        #d = pd.concat([d,data], ignore_index=True)

        d = pd.concat([d,pd.DataFrame(data)], ignore_index = True)
        
print(d)
```

Response :

```
  Type Of Orders  Backlogs
  Base order D     18226
  Base order mount    18226
  move order D     18226 
  move order mount   18226
```

Error:

```
Index: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing\sample.py", line 129, in <module>
    d = pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(data), ignore_index = True)
  File "C:\Users\kunch500\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 709, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "C:\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 481, in dict_to_mgr   
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "C:\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 115, in arrays_to_mgr 
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 645, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You just want the same row repeated multiple times? Can you include your expected output?

Comment: I have edited my question and added sample response in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either supply an index:

```
data = {'Type Of Orders': column, 'Backlogs': 18226}
d = pd.concat([d, pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])])
```

Or just the construction of your dictionary to using lists:

```
data = {'Type Of Orders': [column], 'Backlogs': [18226]}
d = pd.concat([d, pd.DataFrame(data)])
```

Comment: I'm calling function and that function each time returns different values of dictionary and that dictionary i'm trying to concat to dataframe

Comment: See the edit, You need an index.